# How to deploy standalone ServiceStack website

Tags: asp.net, .net, servicestack

I am working on a small website based on an [example ServiceStack project](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku). It is a standalone web app so that there is no need for IIS etc. Currently I start the server at `http://localhost:8080` and opening the website in my local browsers seems to work fine.

My PC has a dedicated IP and I hope to test my server from another computer. I can successfully get a Python server running using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, so network is working fine.

But the remote computer cannot access my ServiceStack server. I think there should be a simple setting somewhere to get it working. But I searched online, there is much information about IIS and ASP.Net. But my app is standalone and is independent of Asp.net. It is supposed to be running on Linux as well as on Windows. (Though I will only deploy on a Windows machine now.)

Comment: Have you opened your windows firewall to allow access to ports 8000 & 8080?

Comment: @Dve I didn't set that. But as the python command line server runs fine, the firewall setting shall be correct. Otherwise it will block python.

Comment: it will work fine on your local computer because the firewall doesnt block local traffic. If you want any other computer to access services running on your machine you will need to open the ports on the firewall

Comment: Thanks. python is an allowed program there. I added my web server, but it still does not work....

Comment: Ok - great. I will add as an answer so the question can be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work fine on your local computer because the firewall doesn't block local traffic. If you want any other computer to access services running on your machine you will need to open the ports on the firewall.

This can be configured from the Windows Firewall in Control Panel